# What does mov eax, [ebx+ecx*4] mean in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, addressing-mode

I just start learning Assembly and got confused by the following expressions.

```
mov ebx, 2

mov ecx, 3

mov eax, [ebx+ecx*4]
```

From what address the data will be moved to eax?

And I don`t understand what is result of the computation of addresses in [ebx+ecx*4]?

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.  What's the source of the code? Is this for a programming [assignment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/)?

Answer (score 2):

14 (= 2 + (3*4)), if I remember well